# How to display a timer in a Cocos2d game?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to display a timer in a cocos2d game which shows the number of minutes:seconds:milliseconds a user has spent on a level.  I've searched for examples and found that I should definitely NOT be using NSTimer.  I understand that I should be using the CCTimer class, but I'm having a tough time finding decent examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//Declare this in interface
CCLabelTTF          *mTimeLbl;
float               mTimeInSec;
```

//Init this in onEnter

```
 mTimeInSec = 0.0f;
 [self schedule:@selector(tick:)];
```

//Function Used

```
-(void)tick:(ccTime)dt
{
    if(self.isGamePaused || self.isGameOver)
        return;

    mTimeInSec +=dt;

    float digit_min = mTimeInSec/60.0f;
    float digit_hour = (digit_min)/60.0f;
    float digit_sec = ((int)mTimeInSec%60);

    int min = (int)digit_min;
    int hours = (int)digit_hour;
    int sec = (int)digit_sec;

    [mTimeLbl setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d:%.2d",hours, min,sec]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `CCLayer` class just create a variable that holds the data and increment it through the timer or through a normal update. I'm giving you some example code but it's just to give you the idea:

```
static long ticks = 0;

-(void)timerTick
{
  ++ticks;
  [(CCLabelBMFont*)[self getChildByTag:TAG_TIMER_STRING] setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu"]];
}

-(id)init {
  ..
  [self schedule:@selector(timerTick) interval:1.0];
}
```